# Twig_Template::getSource() doesn't work until the template has been cached

Tags: twig

I need to load and show a Twig template's source.

The template's getSource() method appears to work by using reflection to find its own class file, and reading the comment block at the end of it (which has the Twig code).

```
public function getSource()
{
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($this);
    $file = $reflector->getFileName();
    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, that file is only available when the template is loaded from the file cache - before then, the class is defined at runtime and the ReflectionClass will return `Environment.php(403) : eval()'d code` as the class file.

```
        if (!class_exists($cls, false)) {
            $content = $this->compileSource($this->getLoader()->getSource($name), $name);
            if ($this->bcWriteCacheFile) {
                $this->writeCacheFile($key, $content);
            } else {
                $this->cache->write($key, $content);
            }

            eval('?>'.$content);
        }
```

Is there any other way I can get the source from Twig, or is it only possible if I find and read the original `.html.twig` file directly?

Answer (score 0):

Oops. The answer was right there in the code, of course:

```
$content = $this->compileSource($this->getLoader()->getSource($name), $name);
```

All I needed was to replace `$environment->loadTemplate($name)->getSource()` with `$environment->getLoader()->getSource($name)`.